# Search for text in Microsoft PowerPoint?

Tags: windows, microsoft-powerpoint

I just simply want to search for text in a presentation with Microsoft PowerPoint. How is this done? I've tried `CTRL + F`, and on Microsoft's page it tells me to choose `Edit`, but there is no `Edit`-button or whatever.

Here is an image of what I'm dealing with.
[image]

Roughly translated menu:

- Hjem - home
- Sett inn - insert/ add
- Utforming - design
- Lysbildefremvisning - presentation
- Se gjennom - review
- Visning - view

Comment: Ctrl+F works on my machine. Have you mapped this shortcut to something else?

Comment: I can't remember last time I used PowerPoint. However, it is mapped to `Ctrl + b` now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select "Hjem" (Home) and then look all the way to the right. There should be a tab group called "Editere" (Editing). The first button in this group should be "Finn" (Find).